# matching random sentences within quotes with regular expression for sublime text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a po file that is 3000 lines long and I need to interchange basically two line patterns like the one  below. I want to be cut the strings that contains **msgid** into the clipboard and then paste them one line below msgstr to interchange their location.

```
   msgid "Detalles del aporte"
msgstr "Contribution details"

#: controller/admin.php:66
msgid "Cambiando el estado al aporte"
msgstr "Contribution details"

#: controller/admin.php:67
msgid "Aporte manual"
msgstr "Manual contribution"

#: controller/admin.php:68
msgid "Reubicando el aporte"
msgstr "Relocating the contribution"

#: controller/admin.php:69
msgid "Ejecución del cargo"
msgstr "Realisation of charge"
```

So far I have come with the following expression

```
(m(sgid\s)([A-Za-z,;'"\\s])$")
```

But I have not been able to proceed further after this, how can i match the rest of the text ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: It should select all the lines that start with msgid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^\s*msgid\s*"(.*?)"$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cQ1tQ4/7)

This would capture the characters which are present within the double quotes only on the lines which contains the string `msgid`